# tic tac toe programming python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem with Tkinter python, can you help me to solve it.

The code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
#Класс приложения, который мы присоединим к интерфейсу GUI

    class TTT(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
            super(TTT, self).__init__(master)
            self.grid()
            self.signs = ["O", "X", "*"]
            self.turn = 1
            self.txt = str(self.turn) +  " ход, ходит 1 игрок"
            self.Widget()
        def Widget(self):
            self.upbs = list()
            self.mibs = list()
            self.dwbs = list()
            for i in range(3):
                self.upbs[i].append(Button(self))
                self.upbs[i].grid(row = 0, column = i)
                self.upbs[i]["text"] = signs[2]
                self.upbs[i]["command"] = self.turn1
            for i in range(3):
                self.upbs[i].append(Button(self))
                self.upbs[i].grid(row = 1, column = i)
                self.upbs[i]["text"] = signs[2]
                self.upbs[i]["command"] = self.turn2
            for i in range(3):
                self.upbs[i].append(Button(self))
                self.upbs[i].grid(row = 2, column = i)
                self.upbs[i]["text"] = signs[2]
                self.upbs[i]["command"] = self.turn3
            self.turn = Label(self, text = txt)
        def turn0(self):
            self.txt = str(turn) + "Это действие нельзя совершить"
        def turn1(self):
            self.upbs[i]["text"] = self.signs[self.turn % 2]
            self.upbs[i]["command"] = self.turn0
            self.turn += 1
            self.txt = str(self.turn) + " ход, ходит " + str(2 - self.turn % 2) + " игрок"
        def turn2(self):
            self.mibs[i]["text"] = self.signs[self.turn % 2]
            self.mibs[i]["command"] = self.turn0
            self.turn += 1
            self.txt = str(self.turn) + " ход, ходит " + str(2 - self.turn % 2) + " игрок"
        def turn3(self):
            self.dwbs[i]["text"] = self.signs[self.turn % 2]
            self.dwbs[i]["command"] = self.turn0
            self.turn += 1
            self.txt = str(self.turn) + " ход, ходит " + str(2 - self.turn % 2) + " игрок"
    #Сама игра
    root = Tk()
    app = TTT(root)
    root.mainloop()**
```

When I run the script I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\XOX.py", line 52, in <module>
    app = TTT(root)   File "C:\Python34\XOX.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.Widget()   File "C:\Python34\XOX.py", line 17, in Widget
    self.upbs[i].append(Button(self)) IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why I am getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a variable using `list()`, it becomes represented as a one dimensional array, i.e. `[ ]`.

The error you are getting (`list index out of range`) means that you are trying to access an element, or index, within the list that does not exist, such as the 5th element of a 4 item list. However, you are using append, which does not access an element but merely adds it onto the end of the list, so where is the problem?

By using `self.upbs[i].append()`, you are trying to access the element of index `i` in the list, but since you have just created the list as `[ ]`, it contains no elements, **so there is no element `i` in the list**, causing an index error.

How to fix? Merely remove the `[i]` calling in the `self.upbs[i].append()`, leaving `self.upbs.append()`, as the first time you append, you will have created element 0 (i.e. first loop of `i`) for the other functions to access in the loop, and so on and so forth.

While this does fix the problem, it does not solve the issue you have that since your list is 1 dimensional, and you are repeatedly looping `i` from 0 to 3, although the appending keeps happening, the `grid` and function assigning continuously happens only to the first 3 elements. This calls for a multidimensional array, i.e. an array of arrays (`[ [item1, item2], [item3, item 4], [item5, item6] ]`), which each array with the main array contains one row of buttons. Since you access an element of an array of an array like so: `array[index1][index2]` (accessing the `index2` element of the `index1` element of the array) all you have to do is create an empty array before the creation of each row of buttons, then assign the buttons into that nested array.

```
 . . .
 self.upbs = list()
 self.mibs = list()
 self.dwbs = list()

 self.upbs.append([])  #adding the first contained array
 for i in range(3):
     #add this row to element 0 of the main array
     self.upbs[0].append(Button(self))
     self.upbs[0][i].grid(row = 0, column = i)
     self.upbs[0][i]["text"] = self.signs[2]
     self.upbs[0][i]["command"] = self.turn1

 self.upbs.append([])  #adding the second contained array
 for i in range(3):
     #add this row to element 1 of the main array
     self.upbs[1].append(Button(self))
     self.upbs[1][i].grid(row = 1, column = i)
 . . .
```